# Routing api to a controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a custom public API; and answer all api requests under ApiController with a routing like this:

```
Route::resource("/api","ApiController");
```

I tried to add this under routes/web or routes/api; but no chance. I get "Sorry..page not found".

Other routing options under routes/web work fine; I only have a problem when it comes to /api.

Should I proceed with a route like /custom_public_api or is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: depending on the size of your project, it may not be that practical to put everything under just one ApiController File

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put this in your `api.php`

```
Route::resource("/users","UserController");
```

Than the routes will be automatically prefixed with `/api`.
So the routes will look like this:

```
/api/users
/api/users/{user}
...
```

So in your case it is not working because you have this type of routes:

```
/api/api
/api/api/{api}
/api/api/{api}/edit
...
```

So you're having api twice. So you just have to suppose that the `api` prefix, is automatically added from `routes/api.php`.

For more information about your routes, you can run `php artisan route:list` and you can check how do your routes look like.

Comment: i would add, that his controller should also be on API/SomeController.php not in the same folder as web controllers. This may be more for organizing the code, but still..

Comment: You probably may not need to change the urls. Because by adding `Route::resource` it automatically generated crud routes. 
You can check what available route you have by running `php artisan route:list`

Comment: By Laravel standard, he should change them... why use a framework if you're not gonna take advantage of what it gives you.

Comment: OK, this helped me. Thank you first of all.
api/products/get_results redirects to show() so I can show data in this point. Also show method gets "get_results" as a parameter, so I can separate different calls in this point...not a good practice, but this would work.

Comment: OK I selected this as the best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For api resources you have to use

`Route::apiResource('photos', 'PhotoController');`

as says in the documantation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) (just scroll a little until you get to **API Resource Routes**)

Comment: Nowhere in the docs it says that you __have__ to use the `apiResource` method when targeting api resources. It is just a convenience to exclude routes that present HTML templates.

Comment: Also, this does not answer the question.